# How to convert a visual studio add-in to an extension?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

I am wondering if it is possible to easily convert a visual studio add-in into a visual studio extension? The add-in is for VS 2010. I am wondering if their is a specific way of doing this, and if it is even worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

All depends upon what your add-in does and how it's written. The primary code that would change is how you connect up to various parts of the IDE; for example, if you expose a command under a menu, the code you use to connect to that menu item will change. Describing what your add-in does might allow for some better recommendations here.

There's no "magic" conversion tool; you'll probably want to just create a new extension project with the SDK and then start to migrate your code over to it.

The extension model is definitely the "newer" model and is where Visual Studio extensibility is headed; practically having the .vsix deployment model can be very convenient way to deploy your extension.

Comment: See also MSDN [FAQ: Converting Add-ins to VSPackage Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246938.aspx).